# How would I add a link to the profile editing page of the dashboard?

Tags: admin, links

Our passwords are handled by an external LDAP server and the plugin we're using to therefore removes all references to the ability to change passwords.

What I'd like to do then, is add a link to the users profile editing page (where they get taken after clicking on their name) which points to our password change page.

How do I add a link here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean `/wp-admin/profile.php` page and want to hide native password fields.

Try this (just test if form works ok with it):

```
add_filter( 'show_password_fields', 'modify_profile_password' );

function modify_profile_password( $show ) {

    ?>
    <tr id="password">
    <th>Change your password at</th>
    <td><a href="">password change page</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being an idiot, but do I put this in functions.php or in its own file located in the plugins folder?

Comment: Should work fine in `functions.php` (written and tested that way).

Comment: Works beautifully. Actually surprised me because the LDAP plugin must have already used that hook to prevent the field from showing.

Comment: WP API, working as it should. Not surprising when plugins try to do same thing. Would be slightly more tricky if one tried to hide and other to show fields.